# AWS FunctionURL Executes the Code Even with Legit CORS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors

I have a Lambda function that is used by multiple projects. To call the Lambda function, I use FunctionURL which is secured by CORS settings, so that it only works from my domains. The system was working fine until recently I added a new domain to the CORS settings.

To test the security, I removed this new domain from "Allow Origin" section. When I call the function, I receive a CORS error, which is expected. But somehow the code still executes!

Here is a screenshot of my FunctionURL settings:
[image]

Here is my request and response:
[image]

And here is the error:
[image]

What might be the reason for the Lambda to execute even when there is a CORS error? Can it be caused by this new domain is HTTP and not HTTPS?

Comment: Keep it mind that CORS information can be cached, which may be the problem here. Clear your cache and try again. HTTP and HTTPS are different Origins from a CORS perspective so if you want to allow HTTP and HTTPS you have to add both. I suggest you try it in a different browser/incognito mode. If there are CORS errors somewhere, please show us.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice , your theory on the caching system makes sense. I tried it again with a new browser and in incognito mode. Same result. Is there a caching mechanism on Lambda side? I also added error screenshot to the original post. Missing CORS header error should be expected I think, but the code is still executed.

Comment: Your request matches the criteria for a "[simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests)", meaning no preflight request is made, the request itself is made, and the response to that request is used to determine if CORS should trigger.  If you want to ensure the preflight happens, you need to do something like set a content-type (and verify the content-type is set on the backend)

Comment: @AnonCoward that was it! To fix the issue, I had to add "Content-Type": "application/json" header to frontend (adding it to backend didn't do anything). Also, I had to keep Expose Headers in Lambda configuration. This way, a preflight request for OPTIONS method happened and everything worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped, just to note:  If you're not checking for the content type in your Lambda, you're still at risk, since a bad actor could trigger your Lambda on another site without sending the proper content type.

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks! Returned error 406 if event.headers["content-type"] != "application/json"